# What is the use of 'sunni' and 'shiite' tags? What are the guidlines on general tags?

Tags: discussion, tag, shia-sunni

Following [a chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15938571#15938571), we decided to have a meta discussion on why we should have [sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunni) and [shiite](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiite) tags.

It was pointed out that the [sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunni) tag can be used for marking questions that ask specifically for a Sunni view point; yet not all past questions use the 'sunni' tag for that purpose and a lot of them tend to presume a Sunni viewpoint without tagging. So if that's the set criterion, we would have to examine and tag a lot of questions as such. Also there are various schools of jurisprudence and different opinions among the Sunnis, which renders the tag as too general.

Pretty much the same goes for the [shiite](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiite). There are various branches within Shiism, although most of the questions in this site come from Twelever Shiites.

So, what's the benefit of these tags and how can we tackle their generality?

Comment: You're referring to [tag:shiism] right? [tag:shiite]'s empty.